# Crystal report include null value

Tags: crystal-reports, null, report

I have a problem with a bar chart in **Crystal Report 13**.

Here's my data:

> mai ABCES BUCCAL
>  juin ABCES BUCCAL
>  juillet 
>  août 
>   septembre
>   octobre 
>  novembre 
>  décembre ABCES BUCCAL
>   janvier ABCES BUCCAL
>  janvier ACCIDENT TRAYON
>  février ABCES
>   BUCCAL
>  mars ABCES BUCCAL
>  mars ABCES BUCCAL
>  mars ABCES
>   BUCCAL
>  mars ABCES BUCCAL
>  mars ABCES BUCCAL
>  avril ABCES
>   BUCCAL
>  avril ABCES BUCCAL
>  avril ABCES BUCCAL
>  avril ABCES
>   BUCCAL
>  avril ACETONEMIE
>  avril ACETONEMIE
>  avril
>   ACETONEMIE
>  avril ACETONEMIE
>  avril ACETONEMIE
>  avril
>   ACETONEMIE
>  avril ACETONEMIE

In my report i have 4 values in my legend :

- ABCES BUCCAL
- ACCIDENT TRAYON,
- ACETONEMIES
- and an empty string

I don't want the month with no event to be count but i want to see all month in my chart even if there's no event.

I hope someone can help me .
Sorry for my english :p
Thanks!

Comment: ISNULL(<Column Name>) function is avaliable is crystal report

Comment: Yeah but how can i use it ?
I'm new in Crystal Report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ISNULL` into formula field of crystal report. You need to created Formula field for that
below is example code of creating formula field

```
if IsNull({table.columname}) then
  CourseType = " ";
else
  CourseType := {table.columname};
```

Comment: Thanks.
I create the formula and add it to the chart but nothing is changing.

Comment: You need to customize the record according to your condition

Comment: I don't see what do you mean ... sorry
Here's my formula :
if IsNull({ChartNormal.Event}) then
    " "
else
    {ChartNormal.Event}

Comment: I found a way to skip them but now the label with no events are not display